# How to move a question to another site?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

Is there a general process to move a question to another site?  Particularly something that was closed on one site as being off topic.  I wanted to move one of my such SO questions but couldn't see how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flag it for migration, if it isn't too old.

If you don't mind losing the votes, answers comments and other historical information that are already posted to it, delete it from the original site, and repost it on the new site (assuming that it is eligible for deletion).

Comment: When deleting questions you should note that this will be rated negatively in the system. I did this a few times and got a warning that my questions were not well received (despite I had no down votes so far). If you do it too often, you might be blocked from asking any more questions...

Answer (score 13):

It's part of the close vote system but it's not obvious how to do it (especially since there's a set of close votes that looks similar for both Super User and Server Fault)

> Close > Off-topic Because... > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

This only works for the 5 sites listed (Meta SO, Super User, Tex, DBA and Stats). Beyond that, you'd have to get a moderator to do it.

Answer (score 11):

The general process for migration: you can close(-vote) the question as off-topic and choose one of the five standard target sister sites. That wouldn't work in your case as the question is already closed.

A second option, which works also if the desired site is not in the list, you could flag the question for moderator attention and explain the situation.